# submit is getting called because of errors object length is zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am for the first time trying to apply validation in a form using `useState` (useform.js). I am checking if the number of errors is 0 before a submit. In my case, the error object has zero keys always so any case the form is getting submitted. Please let me know why its happening. Thanks in advance.

****contactForm****

```js
const ContactForm = () => {
  const { handleChange, contact, handleSubmit, errors, handleOnClick } = useform(
    submit,
    {firstName:"",lastName:"",email:"",phoneNumber:"",message:""}
  )

  function submit(contact) {
    console.log('errors pssed to contact',errors)
    if(Object.keys(errors).length === 0){                  
      contactservice.addContact(contact).then(response => {
        console.log("Response after post api",response.data);    
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log("Error while post api",error)
      })
    }
  } 

  return( 
    <div> 
      <Header/>
      <section id="content">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row aln-center">
            <div className="col-6 col-12-medium">
              <section>
                <header>
                  <h2> Drop your email and phone we will get back !</h2>
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} noValidate>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='First Name'value= 
        {contact.firstName} name='firstName'onChange={handleChange} 
                    autoComplete="off"/>
                    {errors.firstName && <p>{errors.firstName}</p>}<br/>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Last Name'  value= 
               {contact.lastName} name='lastName'onChange={handleChange} 
                    autoComplete="off" /><br/>
                    {errors.lastName && <p>{errors.lastName}</p>}
                    <input type='tel' placeholder='Phone Number'value= 
                     {contact.phoneNumber} name='phoneNumber'onChange= 
                    {handleChange} autoComplete="off" /><br/>
                    {errors.phoneNumber && <p>{errors.phoneNumber}</p>}
                    <input type='email' placeholder='Email'value= 
                     {contact.email} name='email'onChange={handleChange} 
                        autoComplete="off" />
                       {errors.email && <p>{errors.email}</p>}
                    <br/>
                    <textarea  placeholder="Please type what you are 
                    looking from us?" value={contact.message} name 
                   ="message" onChange={handleChange}/><br/>
                    {errors.message && <p>{errors.message}</p>}                              
                    <div className="col-6 col-12-xsmall"> 
                      <button type='submit'>Submit</button>                               
                      <button type='button' onClick= 
                     {handleOnClick}>Cancel</button>
                    </div>                               
                  </form> 
                </header>
              </section>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ContactForm;
```

****useform.js****

```js
const Useform = (callback, validate) => {
  const [contact,setContact] = useState({firstName:"",lastName:"",phoneNumber:"",email:"",message:""});
  const [errors,setErrors] = useState({});
  const [isSubmitting, setIsSubmitting] = useState(false);

  function  handleChange(e){
    setContact({...contact, [e.target.name] : e.target.value })
  }
  
  const handleSubmit = useCallback(e=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("contact from handleSubmit",contact)
    setErrors(validate(contact));     
    callback(contact);     
  });

  function validate(contact){
    let errors={};
    console.log("error object after validation",errors)
    if(contact.firstName ==="") {
      errors.firstName='Enter a valid firstname'
      console.log(" errors.firstName" , errors.firstName)
    }
    if(contact.lastName ==="") {
      errors.lastName='Enter a valid lastname'
      console.log(" errors.lastName" , errors.lastName)
    }
    if(contact.phoneNumber===""){
      errors.phoneNumber='Enter a valid phone number up to 10 digit'
      console.log("errors.phoneNumber" , errors.phoneNumber)
    }
    if(contact.email===""){
      errors.email="Enter a valid email"
      console.log("errors.email" , errors.email)
    }
    else if(!'/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(contact.email)'){
      errors.email="Enter a valid email"
      console.log("errors.email" , errors.email)
    }
    if(contact.message.trim()===""){
      errors.message="enter your message"
      console.log("errors.message" , errors.message)
    }
    return (errors);
  }
}
    const history = useHistory();
    function handleOnClick(){
    history.push('/dashboard');

}

return
```

{handleChange,contact,handleSubmit,errors,handleOnClick,validate,isSubmitting};
export default Useform;

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting but I've possibly screwed it up even more. Could you reformat the code in your editor and paste it back again?

Comment: I also don't understand where does `errors`  variable come from in `submit` function. Do you get any of those console.logs from `useForm` to show up?

Comment: console logs for errors.firstname etc are coming.the whole error object i am not getting.

Comment: Can you add JSX for the submit button or form component? Which function do you call onClick/onSubmit?

Comment: You should probably change it to `callback(contact, errors);` and `function submit(contact, errors) {` but I may be wrong here.

Comment: please for the sake of mankind dont test emails like that

Comment: return {handleChange,contact,handleSubmit,errors,handleOnClick,validate,isSubmitting};

Comment: I don't know what's the point of your last email, but that's not how this works. `errors` is internal to `validate` function and you can't just return it from `useForm`. Please try what I suggested.

Comment: @MikeSzyndel the object is getting passed now ,stiil submit is going on,so what condition i need to add for submit

Comment: ok,The last email I will remove thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you put your code in https://codesandbox.io/ or codepen. Can you do it?

Comment: Yeah, or fix your code so its formatted/readable. I've tried to help you edit it, but I'm not sure it's correct. My best guess is your use of `useCallback` is causing the submit handler to never change even if the inputs change; perhaps you don't need to use `useCallback`.

Comment: I agree with @Jacob here, at this point hooks are entirely unnecessary. I'd suggest writing simple WORKING code first, then improve it if needed by adding hooks, etc.

Comment: @jacob i have just click the edit butto avoe and do it formated rite?i am knew to this ,sorry for asking